# Visa application

Tags: uk-visa

My son is a British citizen through his dad. I would like to know the requirements to apply for a visa to be with him in the UK, the amount I would also need in my bank account when I apply for the visa. I am in Ghana, West Africa now.

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: if he got his citizenship through his father, then you are his father's wife aren't you. You should be eligible to apply for a spousal visa. Visa questions  should ideally be asked on expatriates.SE

Comment: Are you wanting to visit, or to go live in the UK?

Comment: _if he got his citizenship through his father, then you are his father's wife aren't you._ Doesn't always work that way.

Comment: You can start by reading the [Family Visas](https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa)  page on the UK government web site. If you're looking to do more than just visit you should ask further questions on [expatriates.se]

Comment: We are not married. He is married to some one there but im still single. He suggested i come live with our son in the uk.

Comment: Complicates things a bit but since ur son is now a citizen, he should be able to sponsor you. He might need to have a job and accomodation before he does that though

Comment: How old is your son? If a child you may be able to migrate as the parent of a British child who is living in the UK.

Comment: If your son's father made the suggestion, then perhaps he would like to make some inquiries.  If financial support needs to be shown, he may want to provide documentation that he could support you if need be.

Comment: VTC: OP has not returned to either TSE or Expats since asking this question, which needs additional clarification in order to respond.